# How to query list of data files used by a bazel test

Tags: bazel

I have a `cc_test` defined as follows:

```
filegroup(
    name = "test_data",
    srcs = [
        "abc/abc.txt",
        "def.txt",
    ],
)

cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    size = "small",
    srcs = [
        "test_a.cpp",
    ],
    data = [
        ":test_data",
    ],
)
```

I would like to query the `data` files (or `runfiles`) used for this test (in this case `abc/abc.txt` and `def.txt`) using `bazel query`.

I need a list of  data files used by some of my tests to be used in a script.

This is how far I have gotten:

```
$bazel query 'kind("source file", deps(//xxx/...))'
@bazel_tools//tools/test:test-setup.sh
@bazel_tools//tools/test:collect_coverage.sh
@bazel_tools//tools/def_parser:no_op.bat
@bazel_tools//tools/def_parser:def_parser.exe
@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:link_dynamic_library.sh
@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:grep-includes.sh
@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:build_interface_so
@bazel_tools//tools/coverage:dummy_coverage_report_generator
@bazel_tools//third_party/def_parser:def_parser_main.cc
@bazel_tools//third_party/def_parser:def_parser.h
@bazel_tools//third_party/def_parser:def_parser.cc
//xxx:test_a.cpp
//xxx:def.txt
//xxx:abc/abc.txt
```

I only want a subset of this list, that is only the test files (`//xxx:def.txt` and `//xxx:abc/abc.txt`)

Is is possible to do so?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a way to do this using `bazel query`, but we can do this with [Aspects](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html).

Aspects in Bazel allow you to traverse the dependency graph through attribute edges (e.g. `deps` and `srcs`) and create custom actions.

#### Example:

Given this `BUILD` file, we can create a custom rule and aspect to traverse the dependency graph through `deps`, and collect the `data` files into a file.

```python
load("//:collect_data_files.bzl", "collect_data_files")

filegroup(
    name = "test_foo_data",
    srcs = [
        "foo.txt",
        "foo/foo.txt",
    ],
)

cc_test(
    name = "test_foo",
    size = "small",
    srcs = [
        "test_foo.cpp",
    ],
    data = [
        ":test_foo_data",
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "test_bar_data",
    srcs = [
        "bar.txt",
        "bar/bar.txt",
    ],
)

filegroup(
    name = "test_bar_lib_data",
    srcs = [
        "bar_lib.txt",
        "bar_lib/bar_lib.txt",
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "test_bar_lib",
    srcs = ["test_bar_lib.cpp"],
    data = [":test_bar_lib_data"],
)

cc_test(
    name = "test_bar",
    size = "small",
    srcs = [
        "test_bar.cpp",
    ],
    data = [
        ":test_bar_data",
    ],
    deps = [":test_bar_lib"],
)

collect_data_files(
    name = "collect_data",
    testonly = 1,
    deps = [
        "test_bar",
        "test_foo",
    ],
)
```

This is the dependency graph:

[image]

We have two tests, `test_foo` and `test_bar`, which depend on data files. `test_bar` also depends on a `cc_library` that has its own data files.

In `collect_data_files.bzl`, we create an **aspect** to collect the data files on targets through the `deps` attribute transitively.

```python
DataFilesInfo = provider(
    fields = {
        "data_files": "Data files for this target",
    },
)

def _collect_data_aspect_impl(target, ctx):
    data_files = []
    if hasattr(ctx.rule.attr, "data"):
        for src in ctx.rule.attr.data:
            for f in src.files:
                data_files += [f]
    for dep in ctx.rule.attr.deps:
        data_files += dep[DataFilesInfo].data_files
    return [DataFilesInfo(data_files = data_files)]

collect_data_aspect = aspect(
    attr_aspects = [
        "deps",
    ],
    implementation = _collect_data_aspect_impl,
)
```

Then in the same file, we can define the `collect_data_files` rule to write the list of target labels and their data files into a file.

```python
def _collect_data_rule_impl(ctx):
    data_files_string = ""
    for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
        data_files = [f.path for f in dep[DataFilesInfo].data_files]
        data_files_string += str(dep.label) + ","
        data_files_string += ",".join(data_files) + "\n"
    ctx.actions.write(ctx.outputs.data_files, data_files_string)

collect_data_files = rule(
    attrs = {
        "deps": attr.label_list(aspects = [collect_data_aspect]),
    },
    outputs = {
        "data_files": "%{name}_data_files.txt",
    },
    implementation = _collect_data_rule_impl,
)
```

Now, we can build the `collect_data_files` target:

```
$ bazel build :collect_data
INFO: Analysed target //:collect_data (10 packages loaded).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:collect_data up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/collect_data_data_files.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.966s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
```

The results are written into the output file:

```
$ cat bazel-bin/collect_data_data_files.txt
//:test_bar,bar.txt,bar/bar.txt,bar_lib.txt,bar_lib/bar_lib.txt
//:test_foo,foo.txt,foo/foo.txt
```

Comment: Seems like a lot of work, I am for now filtering the output of `bazel query 'kind("source file", deps(//xxx/...))'` based on file extension, my data files are all `.data`. BTW how to generate that dependency graph image?

Comment: `bazel query 'deps(//my:target)’  --noimplicit_deps --output=graph > target_graph.in && dot -Tpng < target_graph.in > target_graph.png`